# isset() return false for a non-null private property

Tags: php, isset

I can't understand why if I execute this code, it print true

```
$a = $myobject[0]->myproperty;
echo isset($a) ? "true" : "false";
```

But with this one the result is false:

```
echo isset($myobject[0]->myproperty) ? "true" : "false";
```

An object property is not interpreted as a variable by PHP? In the 2nd situation, I simply replaced the variable $a, directly inserting the instruction in its place.

```
$m = MyObject::ByAttributes("My text on attribute property");
$myobject = [$m];
```

Class definition:

```
<?php
class MyObject implements JsonSerializable {
  private $myproperty;

  public static function ByAttributes($myproperty) {
    $instance = new self();
    $instance->myproperty = $myproperty;
    return $instance;
  }

  public static function ByQuery(object $result) {
    $instance = new self();
    $instance->myproperty = isset($result->myproperty) ? $result->myproperty : null;
    return $instance;
  }

  public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      return $this->$property;
    }
  }

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      $this->$property = $value;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function jsonSerialize() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return get_class($this) . "{" . implode(",", get_object_vars($this)) . "}";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us the object class (`$myobject[0]`) property (`->myproperty`). Is it set in the class or set in the script before `$a`?

Comment: What's `var_dump` of `$a`?

Comment: According to a user contributed note in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#51113) seems that `$foo->bar` is not considered a variable, so `isset()` returns `false`.

Comment: @Valentino Thanks but this is so weird. 13 years have been passed and have not yet understood that a parameter of an object is a variable (reference on memory?)

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev string(29) "My text on attribute property"

Comment: @Davide Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have, including the class definition.

Comment: Question improved

Comment: Why are you trying to access `myproperty` when it is declared as private? Isn't that what your `__get()` function is for?

Comment: @kojow7 I don't access to the private property. Do you see getter/setter in the class definition?

Comment: @Davide You might want to look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `isset($myobject[0]->myproperty)` you have to implement the magic `__isset` in your method to get a valid result for calling `isset`

```
public function __isset($property) {
    return isset($this->$property);
}
```

[php.net - __isset](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset)

Comment: Wooow! This really answer my question. Thank you

Comment: This works, albeit PHPStorm still marks the properties with an error as it still recognizes them as you trying to access a private property. Maybe passing the property name as a string could avoid it, but I think then you would have to create a method.

Answer (score 2):

Your `myproperty` property is private, so from outside the class the property is not visible.

```
class Foobar {
    private $bla = 42;
}
$o = new Foobar;
var_dump($o);
var_dump(isset($o));
var_dump(isset($o->bla));
```

This will generate the following output:

```
object(Foobar)#1 (1) {
  ["bla":"Foobar":private]=>
  int(42)
}
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

(on PHP 7.2.14 (cli), but may be the same for 7.3.1)

Comment: Thank you, if I change the myproperty attribute to public it works. But I want to keep that variable private... why PHP try to access it directly and not through the overloading mechanism?